# Embed Console Application in WPF application on load

Tags: c#, wpf, console, console-application

I would like some tips in order to solve this or even a solution for this little problem that i am stuck at the moment.

I have written a WPF code and I want to embed console application into it. What I am doing is first I have opened the console.exe and once it is opened outside WPF I am trying to embed it into my WPF application.

The scenario above works absolutely fine if I embed the application on the button click such as below,

**TO OPEN Console APP**

```
            string exe = @"cmd.exe";
            var processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(exe);
            processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exe);
            cmdProcess = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

**And then to embed it into WPF application:**

(Note: Whenever I am running the below code on button click it works fine, however I want it to run on loading on the form after **InitializeComponent()** method)

```
            System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();

            Win32API.SetParent(cmdProcess.MainWindowHandle, panel.Handle);

            winFormsHost.Child = panel;
```

The code above works fine on the button click. However, I do not want to click the button to embed it into my WPF application I want to directly load the WPF application and embed my console app into it without doing anything manually.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What prevents you from doing it ?

Comment: Console app is yours? If yes, you could compile it to DLL library, then call it's methods via your own objects and not browsing, starting process.
About your question: InitalizeComponents() method doesn't mean to do that. You could call your process right after InitalizeComponents() in your Window's constructor or before if components depends on your process' run.